# Is there a web component (unpkg) for React-Day-Picker that works?

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

The unpkg paths listed in the documentation report "no file found" when I paste them into a browser window.  Is there a path that works?

https://unpkg.com/react-day-picker/daypicker.min.js

https://unpkg.com/react-day-picker/lib/style.css

Comment: https://unpkg.com/ is down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered on GitHub.  The correct paths are:

https://unpkg.com/react-day-picker/lib/daypicker.min.js

[href="https://unpkg.com/react-day-picker/lib/style.css](http://href=%22https://unpkg.com/react-day-picker/lib/style.css)